# Question about relation of $\gamma$ , $H_n $ and $ \ln(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $\gamma = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (H_n - \ln(n))$

Can we write $\ln(n) = H_n - (\gamma + \epsilon) $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Edit $ \epsilon $ for error term

From $$\ln(n) = H_n - (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (H_n - \ln(n)) + \epsilon) $$

Can I split into $$\ln(n) = H_n - (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} H_n - \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(n) + \epsilon) $$
Then how $\epsilon$ work

and why $H_{n}= \ln(n)+\gamma$ for the large $n$

Since $H_{n}= \ln(n)+\gamma + \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+\frac{1}{120n^4}- \epsilon$
for   $0 < \epsilon <\frac{1}{252n^6} $

Can we banish the last 4 term for large $n$ number

Comment: "Can we write...." No, of course not: First, "for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$..." ?? Second, what is $\;\epsilon\;$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry $\epsilon$ is for error term

Comment: "Can I split into" No. $\lim (f+g) = \lim f + \lim g$ only when all three limits exist (and yours don't).

Comment: Going from the limit to your claimed result isn't really valid, but you CAN start with the infinite series and derive what you want. Your last paragraph looks really good. It's perfectly fine to say that $\log n = H_n - \gamma + O(1/n)$ which can be expressed with the notation $\log n \sim H_n - \gamma$. As you note in your last few lines, this error is clearly positive and can be bounded. Call this error "$\epsilon$" and you're done